# Which financial time series have a PDF and/or CDF?

Tags: distribution, asset-returns, density, pdf, cdf

Consider the following types of financial time series for a single publicly-listed stock:

1. Price data
2. Log returns
3. Cumulative returns

Each is computed from the item listed before it: log returns are based on differences of prices, and cumulative returns are cumulative products of log returns.

- Which of the random variables listed above possess a probability distribution function (PDF),
- which have a cumulative distribution function (CDF), and
- which have both a PDF and CDF?
- for what sort of financial applications is the CDF preferred over the PDF, and vice versa?

I ask because the following [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3473846/) says all random variables have a CDF, but not all of them have a PDF. So I wanted to see how this applies to commonly used financial data, which are prices and returns. Graphical depictions of the above datas' CDF and PDFs displayed side-by-side would help in the explanation.

I'm particularly curious about cumulative returns. Since they're cumulative, it automatically makes me think it corresponds and is represented best by a CDF, so in a way I'm wondering if cumulative returns are more useful than they're made out to be, despite being non-stationary.

Comment: They don't have pdf because they have a pmf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a continuous variable the PDF is the derivative of CDF. So returns or prices don't have a pdf if the cdf is not differentiable, e.g. it "jumps" at some point. The simplest models we use, like normally distributed log-returns, imply that returns, cumulative returns and prices all have a pdf.

Comment: You say all 3 have a pdf. And which of them have cdf? Stock returns usually aren't normal log returns, stocks have nonnormal log returns.

Comment: @develarist As you said any random variable has a cdf. I just meant we commonly assume all 3 have a pdf. Most of the common distributions like normal, t, gamma all have a pdf., normality is not important here. But you can find counterexamples mentioned in the previous post like some mixture models for which the pdf does not exist.

Comment: @develarist I also don't see why one of these would be more likely to have a pdf than the others. Typically if you assume returns don't have a pdf, then prices won't either.

Comment: here is a separate question, https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/55797